# Single line multiple assignment in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it good to assign an empty array in one line ?

```
arun@arun:~$ irb
   irb(main):001:0> a = b = c = []
=> []
irb(main):002:0> b << "one"
=> ["one"]
irb(main):003:0> p a
["one"]
=> nil
```

Since i expect 'a' to be [] but it show the value of b means "one".  Is this expect one ?

I also try with string and integer object.

```
irb(main):004:0> d = e = f = 0
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> f = 6
=> 6
irb(main):006:0> p d
0
=> nil
irb(main):007:0>

irb(main):007:0> q = w = e = r = "jak"
=> "jak"
irb(main):008:0> e = "kaj"
=> "kaj"
irb(main):009:0> p w
"jak"
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> p e
"kaj"
=> nil
irb(main):011:0>
```

It is working as i expected. Then why not array ?

Comment: `a, b, c, d = (0..3).map{ [] }`

Comment: Hey Michael Kohl, Thanks for the quick response. Now i am clear.

Comment: Hey Victor, that example is useful...

Answer (score 30):

What you are doing is assingning `[]` to `c`, which you then assign to `b`, which finally gets assigned to `a`.

```
>> a = b = c = []
>> a.object_id
=> 2152679240
>> b.object_id
=> 2152679240
>> c.object_id
=> 2152679240
```

What you want is

```
>> a,b,c = [], [], []
=> [[], [], []]
>> a.object_id
=> 2152762780
>> b.object_id
=> 2152762760
>> c.object_id
=> 2152762740
```

Edit: the examples work because you just go and plain assign a new value (`Fixnum`s can't be mutated anyway). Try modifying the string in-place instead:

```
>> q = w = e = r = "jak"
=> "jak"
>> e << 'i'
=> "jaki"
>> w
=> "jaki"
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby everything is an object, including `[]`, `0`, and `"jak"` (an instance of Array, Integer, and String, respectively). You are assigning the same object to multiple variables -- if you change that object (`b << "one"`), then every variable referencing that object will reflect the change. When you use the assignment operator `=` you are not changing the object -- you are assigning a new object to the variable.

In Michael Kohl's last example (), he is using `<<` which modifies the String object referenced by the variable. That is why the variable still references the same object and all strings referencing that object reflect the change.